# xsl: how to tell if a variable has been declared

Tags: xslt

I have a variable in my xsl that may or may not be declared.  How can I tell if it has been declared.

The issue is I have 2 style sheets.  A parent (where the global variable is declared) and a child (where the global variable is referenced).  I usually call the parent stylesheet which then calls the child stylesheet.  So everything is fine because the variable is declared.  But I sometimes call the child style sheet by itself.

So the easiest solution for me is a way to check if the variable has been declared before trying to use it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xsl you cannot tell if a variable is declared.

The solution I came up with, was having an interim xsl file that declared the variable and then imported the "child" xsl file.

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessary.

XSLT is a declarative language. You can't use a stylesheet that has undeclared references, because that is a compile-time error, not a run-time error.

Which means that if the stylesheet compiles at all, it will never run into an "undeclared variable" error by definition.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: See my changes.  (I have multiple stylesheets.)  Thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your stylesheet is referencing a second sheet where you are not certain of the contents, try xsl:import (as opposed to xsl:include).

Comment: The child stylesheet never imports or includes the parent.  I just need to tell at runtime if the variable has been initialized.

Comment: What mechanism are you using to establish the relationship if not import or include? If you import, you can declare the variable in such a way that import precedence will either set a value to the variable or set an empty string. You can then test whether $foo!=''.

Comment: The parent is importing the child, but that is not really relevant.  Because the problem is that sometimes I have ANT calling only the child stylesheet, not the parent.  The variable is never declared in the child so this throws an error.  I need to be able to check if the variable is declared, and perform some action.

Comment: So in your child, declare <xsl:variable name="foo" select="''"/>. This will be overridden in the parent when the child is imported. You can then test in the child <xsl:choose><xsl:when test="$foo=''">Child only</xsl:when><xsl:otherwise>Called via Parent</xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose>. The variable will always be present but you can initialize it only when you call from the parent.